# threads running in sequence

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to java and I am wondering how to do something I was asked in an interview question.

You have three threads `T1`, `T2` and `T3`.
How do you ensure that they finish in order `T1`, `T2`, `T3`.
Interviewer asked me to write the program on it.
I know that this question can be answered by the concept of `join` or `count down latch` but some how I was not able to be successful.
Could you guys please show me how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create 3 threads but dont start them,  then go as follows

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
t2.join();
t3.start();
```

Thread.join waits for a thread to terminate, so the order is guaranteed

Comment: Doesn't it join main thread to these (t1, t2 and t3) instead of joining t3 to t2 and t2 to t2. I tried it and somehow it worked everytime.. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is a trick question. I would ask the interviewer why he wants them to finish in a particular order. Frankly, I cannot see any situation where I would want separate threads to finish in a particular order other than the main thread waiting for its children.

Comment: the interviewer want to test me please advise

Comment: If the only requirement is that the threads finish in a particular orden, then Evgeniy answer is a viable solution. However, employers tend to want employees who do their own thinking and speak up when a requirement is unclear or when a design solution is sub-par. In my book, the ability to design effective solutions is more important than knowing a particular interface by heart. The specifics of an interface is available in the javadoc. Learning how to write effective solutions is much harder and requires both experience and aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of doing this. The easiest would be to use [Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29), which will cause the current thread to pause until the thread you're invoking `join()` on has finished:

```
someThread.join();
// the current thread won't continue until someThread completes
```

Then, you can have T3 join on T2, and T2 join on T1.

But if I were you, I'd have asked the interviewer *why* they want the threads to complete in that order. Is it because T3 consumes something that T2 produces? If so, something like a [concurrent queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) might be better, because it's less fragile -- you can change which thread does the work of consuming or producing the thing without things breaking. Heck, the producer/consumer threads could be set up to *never* finish, but rather have one producing as fast as it can and the other consuming as fast as it can. Threads are all about *not* knowing the order in which things happen, except for certain touch points (such something being ready to be consumed).

So basically, the question as presented is a bit bogus.

Answer (score 0):

if threads are supposed to finish in order, then why not put the code of all three in 1 thread's run?